# Add external library to Ubuntu App in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, c++, qml, cmake

I am trying to add the QuaZip library to my project (https://launchpad.net/vadetux). I have tried setting the EXEC variable in the CMakeLists.txt to:

```
set(EXEC "qmlscene -I /usr/include/quazip $@ ${VADETUX-ES-ES_DIR}/${MAIN_QML}")
```

and:

```
set(EXEC "qmlscene -I ${QUAZIP_IMPORT_DIR} $@ ${VADETUX-ES-ES_DIR}/${MAIN_QML}")
```

being QUAZIP_IMPORT_DIR equivalent to /usr/lib/${ARCH_TRIPLET} (x86_64-linux-gnu in my case), which is where the libquazip.so/a files are.

In any case, I can only get the bug described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/vadetux/+bug/1383655 even when trying to copy all the header files and libraries to the project and including them from there.

How can I make this unzip function work with quazip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use QuaZip in the [Epub module](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/tree/master/epubreader) of Beru.  But I've taken a different approach and just compile QuaZip as part of my module.  [This CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/blob/master/epubreader/CMakeLists.txt) shows how I did it.

I'm not sure if the QuaZip .so is included in the Touch image, or if the apparmor restrictions allow you to use it if it is, so this seemed the safest approach.

Comment: That has solved it, I will go for that